# Can't find link in Excel Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a macro to open several password protected workbooks. The workbooks all have links between each other so for the sake of convenience, I've set `UpdateLinks:=0` so that I do not get prompted for passwords for all the link updates, before the other books have opened.

After all the workbooks are open, i am trying to then update the links using

```
Workbooks("Workbook1").UpdateLink Type:=1
Workbooks("Workbook2").UpdateLink Type:=1
Workbooks("Workbook3").UpdateLink Type:=1
Workbooks("Workbook4").UpdateLink Type:=1
```

This is more convenient since the workbooks are now open so no password prompt is required.

This works fine on two of the workbooks but the other two are prompting me to locate the source of a link which does not exist.. That is the actual link does not exist in the workbook..

I've spent hours trying to figure out where it is getting this link from but it simply does not exist anywhere..

To make this more clear, in workbook 2 I have three links A, B, and C. These are visible in the Data > Edit links menu. However, when i run the macro it asks me to locate the source of link E...

I've tried the below to see if there is a link not visible for some reason

```
Workbooks("Workbook2").Activate

aLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(1)
If Not IsEmpty(aLinks) Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(aLinks)
        MsgBox "Link " & i & ":" & Chr(13) & aLinks(i) 
    Next i
End If
```

This just shows me the three I can see in Edit Links.

I've searched the workbook for the name of the link it's trying to get me to locate the file for and nothing..

Has anyone seen this before or got any ideas? it's got me stumped and has made what should have been a simple job really frustrating.

Comment: Suggest you try Bill Manville's [findlink](http://www.manville.org.uk/software/findlink.htm) addin

Comment: Brilliant, thanks brettdj - addin found it in a "hidden name".. which i'm not familiar with. I had searched through all the formulas already. i had no idea there was a hidden name in there.

Comment: names inside ranges or chart are normally the "hidden" offenders, glad it worked.

Comment: Mike or @brettdj, can you convert the comment to an answer?  Seems like a bit of useful stuff here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links between workbooks can be created (on purpose or by accident) in a number of ways:

```
1. Within formulae 
2. Inside range names
3. Inside chart ranges
```

Excel users are typically familiar with (1), and searching for text that references the links, but this wont detect links in charts and range names.

Bill Manville's [findlink](http://www.manville.org.uk/software/findlink.htm) is the standout solution for finding and/or removing these links.

Download the addin, select the file with the links, run the addin from Excel (instructions on Bill's page) and then

- select the reference you are looking to find in the drop-down box
- I pick the option that finds and then lists the links

*sample of various link types*

[image]

*sample output*

[image]

Some years back I had a crack at writing my own link finder, code below in case it proves of use

*code*

```
Option Explicit

' This code searches all sheets (worksheets and chart sheets) in the ActiveWorkbook for links
' and compiles a filtered CSV file to report on any:
' #1 Formula links (and validates them against linksources)
' #2 Range Name links
' #3 PivotTable links
' #4a Chart Series links (in both Chart Sheets and Charts on regular Worksheets)
' #4b Chart Title links (in both Chart Sheets and Charts on regular Worksheets)

' Download Bill Manville's FindLink at http://www.bmsltd.co.uk/MVP/Default.htm
' for a tool to manage (ie delete) links

' Notes
' 1) The Chart title method relies on activating the Chart.
'         ---> Protected sheets are skipped
'         ---> This method does not work in xl2007
' 2) I have deliberately left out error handling as I want to resolve any issues

Sub ListLinks()
    Dim objFSO As Object, objFSOfile As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook, sh
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rArea As Range
    Dim chr As ChartObject, chr1 As Chart
    Dim lSource, PivCh, chrSrs
    Dim FSOFileHeader As String, tmpStr As String, chrTitle As String, FirstAddress As String, ReportFile As String, ShProt As String
    Dim nameCnt As Long
    Dim FndRngLink As Boolean, FndChrLink As Boolean, FndNameLink As Boolean, FndPivLink As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'location of report file
    ReportFile = "c:\LinkReport.csv"
    FSOFileHeader = "Type,Object Level,Location,Linked Workbook,Full Linked File Path,Reference"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    On Error Resume Next
    'if report file is open then ask user to close it
    Set objFSOfile = objFSO.createtextfile(ReportFile)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Pls close " & vbNewLine & ReportFile & vbNewLine & "then re-run code"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'write report file headers
    With objFSOfile
        .writeline ActiveWorkbook.Path & "," & ActiveWorkbook.Name
        .writeline FSOFileHeader
    End With

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        Select Case sh.Type
        Case xlWorksheet
            'look at formula cells in each worksheet
            Set rng1 = Nothing
            Set rng2 = Nothing
            Set rng3 = Nothing

            On Error Resume Next
            Set rng1 = sh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
            On Error GoTo 0
            Application.StatusBar = "Searching formulas in sheet " & sh.Name
            If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
                'look for *.xls
                With rng1
                    Set rng2 = .Find("*.xls", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)
                    If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
                        FirstAddress = rng2.Address
                        'validate that the *.xls is part of a linksource
                        For Each lSource In ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
                            'look in open and closed workbooks
                            If InStr(Replace(rng2.Formula, "[", vbNullString), lSource) > 0 Or InStr(rng2.Formula, Right$(rng2.Formula, Len(lSource) - InStrRev(lSource, "\"))) > 0 Then
                                FndRngLink = True
                                'write to the report file
                                Set rng3 = rng2
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                        'repeat till code loops back to first formula cell containing "*.xls"
                        Do
                            Set rng2 = .FindNext(rng2)
                            If rng2.Address <> FirstAddress Then
                                For Each lSource In ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
                                    If InStr(Replace(rng2.Formula, "[", vbNullString), lSource) > 0 Or InStr(rng2.Formula, Right$(lSource, Len(lSource) - InStrRev(lSource, "\"))) > 0 Then
                                        Set rng3 = Union(rng3, rng2)
                                        Exit For
                                    End If
                                Next
                            End If
                        Loop Until rng2.Address = FirstAddress
                    End If
                End With
            End If

            If Not rng3 Is Nothing Then
                For Each rArea In rng3.Areas
                    objFSOfile.writeline "Formula," & "Range" & "," & sh.Name & "!" & Replace(rArea.Address(0, 0), ",", ";") & "," & Right$(lSource, Len(lSource) - InStrRev(lSource, "\")) & "," & lSource & ",'" & rng3.Cells(1).Formula
                Next
            End If

            ' Charts
            For Each chr In sh.ChartObjects
                Application.StatusBar = "Searching charts in sheet " & sh.Name
                For Each chrSrs In chr.Chart.SeriesCollection
                    If InStr(chrSrs.Formula, ".xls") <> 0 Then
                        For Each lSource In ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
                            'look in open and closed workbooks
                            If InStr(Replace(chrSrs.Formula, "[", vbNullString), lSource) > 0 Or InStr(chrSrs.Formula, Right$(lSource, Len(lSource) - InStrRev(lSource, "\"))) > 0 Then
                                FndChrLink = True
                                'write to the report file
                                objFSOfile.writeline "Chart Series," & chr.Name & "," & sh.Name & "," & Right$(lSource, Len(lSource) - InStrRev(lSource, "\")) & "," & lSource & ",'" & Replace(chrSrs.Formula, ",", ";")
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                Next chrSrs

                If chr.Chart.HasTitle Then
                    If sh.ProtectContents = True Then
                        ShProt = ShProt & sh.Name & " - " & chr.Name & vbNewLine
                    Else
                        chr.Activate
                        chrTitle = CStr(ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.FORMULA(""Title"")"))
                        If InStr(chrTitle, ".xls") <> 0 Then
                            For Each lSource In ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
                                'look in open and closed workbooks
                                If InStr(Replace(chrTitle, "[", vbNullString), lSource) > 0 Or InStr(chrTitle, Right$(lSource, Len(lSource) - InStrRev(lSource, "\"))) > 0 Then
                                    FndChrLink = True
                                    'write to the report file
                                    objFSOfile.writeline "Chart Title," & chr.Name & "," & sh.Name & "," & Right$(lSource, Len(lSource) - InStrRev(lSource, "\")) & "," & lSource & ",'" & chrTitle
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            Next
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

            Next chr

            'Pivot Tables
            For Each PivCh In sh.PivotTables
                If InStr(PivCh.SourceData, ".xls") > 0 Then
                    For Each lSource In ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
                        If InStr(Replace(PivCh.SourceData, "[", vbNullString), lSource) > 0 Or InStr(PivCh.SourceData, Right$(lSource, Len(lSource) - InStrRev(lSource, "\"))) > 0 Then
                            objFSOfile.writeline "Pivot Table," & PivCh.Name & "," & sh.Name & "," & Right$(lSource, Len(lSource) - InStrRev(lSource, "\")) & "," & lSource & ",'" & PivCh.SourceData
                            FndPivLink = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        Case 3
            Set chr1 = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set chr1 = sh
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not chr1 Is Nothing Then
                Application.StatusBar = "Searching charts in sheet " & sh.Name
                For Each chrSrs In chr1.SeriesCollection
                    If InStr(chrSrs.Formula, ".xls") <> 0 Then
                        For Each lSource In ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
                            'look in open and closed workbooks
                            If InStr(Replace(chrSrs.Formula, "[", vbNullString), lSource) > 0 Or InStr(chrSrs.Formula, Right$(lSource, Len(lSource) - InStrRev(lSource, "\"))) > 0 Then
                                FndChrLink = True
                                'write to the report file
                                objFSOfile.writeline "Chart Series,Chart Sheet," & sh.Name & "," & Right$(lSource, Len(lSource) - InStrRev(lSource, "\")) & "," & lSource & ",'" & Replace(chrSrs.Formula, ",", ";")
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                Next

                If chr1.HasTitle Then
                    chr1.Activate
                    chrTitle = CStr(ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.FORMULA(""Title"")"))
                    If InStr(chrTitle, ".xls") <> 0 Then
                        For Each lSource In ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
                            'look in open and closed workbooks
                            If InStr(Replace(chrTitle, "[", vbNullString), lSource) > 0 Or InStr(chrTitle, Right$(lSource, Len(lSource) - InStrRev(lSource, "\"))) > 0 Then
                                FndChrLink = True
                                'write to the report file
                                objFSOfile.writeline "Chart Title,Chart Sheet," & sh.Name & "," & Right$(lSource, Len(lSource) - InStrRev(lSource, "\")) & "," & lSource & ",'" & Replace(chrTitle, ",", ";")
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Case Else
        End Select
        'End If
    Next sh

    'Named ranges
    If ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count = 0 Then
    Else
        Application.StatusBar = "Searching range names"
        For nameCnt = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count
            If InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Names(nameCnt), ".xls") <> 0 Then
                For Each lSource In ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
                    If InStr(Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Names(nameCnt), "[", vbNullString), lSource) > 0 Or InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Names(nameCnt), Right$(lSource, Len(lSource) - InStrRev(lSource, "\"))) > 0 Then
                        FndNameLink = True
                        'write to the report file
                        objFSOfile.writeline "Range Name," & "Workbook level," & ActiveWorkbook.Names(nameCnt).Name & "," & Right$(lSource, Len(lSource) - InStrRev(lSource, "\")) & "," & lSource & ",'" & ActiveWorkbook.Names(nameCnt).RefersTo
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                'Name link does not exist in "known" links
                If FndNameLink = False Then
                    FndNameLink = True
                    objFSOfile.writeline "Range Name," & "Workbook level," & ActiveWorkbook.Names(nameCnt).Name & "," & ActiveWorkbook.Names(nameCnt) & ",'" & Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Names(nameCnt).RefersTo, ",", ";")
                End If
            End If
        Next nameCnt
    End If

    'Close the report file
    objFSOfile.Close
    Set objFSO = Nothing

    'If at least one cell link was found then open report file
    If (FndChrLink = FndNameLink = FndRngLink = FndPivLink) And FndRngLink = False Then
        MsgBox "No formula links found", vbCritical
    Else
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ReportFile)
        With wb.Sheets(1)
            .Rows("1:2").Font.Bold = True
            .Columns("A:F").AutoFit
            .[A2].AutoFilter
        End With
    End If
    With Application
        .StatusBar = vbNullString
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    If ShProt <> vbNullString Then MsgBox "The following sheets were protected " & vbNewLine & "so these Chart titles could not be searched" & vbNewLine & ShProt, vbCritical
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again brettdj, it worked a treat. The offending link was in a hidden .wvu.filterdata named range.

Comment: would this also find links in vba parts of a workbook, like buttons linking to external macros?

Comment: @DutchArjo  no. That would need a different approach