# Error on excel external links

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting this error of "We can`t connect to ".... .xlsm" file. I checked the external links and tried to break the link but I was not able to break it. I also tried the following codes in workbook.open but I am still getting errors when opening the file:

ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

I also tried data validation/circle invalid data to find the external links in my excel file, but I was not able to see them.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Will probably need more info, meanwhile I suggest to try shorten the target .xlsm file (abc.xlsm) and put it in the same directory as the source file.  If that works for you starts debugging from there.

Comment: Ensure that the location (if network based) is direct to the location (\\locale) rather than using your labels (C:), as well as ensure that the path or the file name don't include symbols that the system doesn't like (I know # is an issue for a lot of sites/networks).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find link in Excel Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368582/cant-find-link-in-excel-workbook)